# mvc6 jquery referenced file not found

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

this is doing my head in a bit.

Under ASP5 MVC6 I have not been able to get JQuery to be sourced.

I have set the app.UseStaticFiles(); it is set set before the useMVC() as below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
        HttpService.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
        app.UseSession();         
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

my layout file seems to be serving up the .css fine but not the scripts. I can even navigate/view through the browser to the relative js file it loads the text in the browser.

Visual studio always has the same message though ( even though the path is correct )

07:27:35.4149: Referenced file '~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' not found.
07:27:35.4149: Referenced file '~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' not found.

in my layout:

```
<body>
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Navigation")
@RenderBody()
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: maybe you try to access it via the filesystem path? You need to access the script via the web server path.

Comment: I tried using using Url.Content() but same issue

Comment: no no, just think simple: write something like `http://localhost/yourproject` in it. Or just the path to the file under the base url. PS: When you run your application take the browser address and try to figure the base path out. This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly enough I was simply missing a @section scripts { } on one of my pages and was being distracted by the fact that debugger kept saying it couldnt find the .js at the file path.

I dont know why the vs2015 debugger constantly says it cant reference the file, but it does work properly now when its launched..